# PrimeFaces: input mask for numbers

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I would like to use an input mask for the numbers, but i can't figure out how to do this kind of mask
The mask I'm seeking should be like this:
number,number,number,number
where the number can be any positive number with no limits on digits number

Comment: Not sure that you can do it with mask element, look at this plugin : http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/views/keyFilter.jsf

Comment: What do you mean by "mask"? Do you mean the kind of masking that a password field does? Or the dummy text that's displayed on an input field before a user actually enters anything in the field?

Comment: look here: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputMask.xhtml , let's look at date, i want something like date, but without limits of the digits number on every field

Comment: I think your case is not a mask rather than a validator!

Comment: For example you could have a regex validator ! see http://regexr.com/39k0p